# Where's the ASP.Net WebService in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio

I am trying to create my first webservice.  I've been googling for a tutorial or examples and most of what I find is from previous versions of Visual Studio and say to create a new ASP.Net Webservice...but that doesn't exist in 2010!

What I need to do is have the service receive 2 strings, an agency and a man number.  Then run a query to get some information and return a string with a date and time back to the requestor.  I need to have a web interface available to call the service as well.

Any guidance on what I need to do to create the service in Visual Studio 2010 in C# will be appreciated!

Update:  I've just been told that this process needs to authenticate the users...can someone guide me to information on implementing certificate or digital signatures into my web service?  I've looked but most of what I'm finding is for authenticating through Active Directory or some other maintained list with usernames and passwords.

Comment: whoooo! that just freaked me out - never seen that before my sad answer now gone

Comment: i noticed that it disappeared too....thought maybe you had deleted it :(

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This puzzled me too. There's another puzzle to be had when you try and add a reference to an ASP.NET Web Service too, but I'll let you have fun with that one.

Change the target framework version in the dropdown list to `.NET framework 2` and choose `Web` on the left hand side when creating a new project and it will appear.

---

Actually, I'm not going to be mean. If you are going to reference the web service from an application built using.NET 3.0 or higher:

1. Go to `Add Service Reference`
2. Go to Advanced
3. Click Add Web Reference at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: hooray! you're right - by changing the Framework it appears!  I'll accept the answer as soon as SO lets me!

Comment: Ok I don't know if I'm going to "reference the web service from an application built using .NET 3.0" or not....like I said this is my first one!

Answer (score 10):

In VS 2010, you can't create web services because this is covered with WCF services.
To create ASP.NET Web Services, you need to select ASP.NET app with Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 7):

**Visual Studio 2010 SP1, .NET Framwework 4.0**
You need to create **ASP.NET web site**, and then **Add New Item** and there select from **Web** tab template **Web Service.**

Comment: You need to add a new Web Site first, and then add the Web service item.  You don't need to create a "web page" at all.

Answer (score 4):

Consider creating a WCF service instead. This is the evolutionary successor of the 'bare' Webservice.

When you configure the WCF server with BasicHttpBinfing you have a (SOAP) Webservice. Other binding-types (including more advanced WS-* webservices) only require changes in the config.

But for an old-style ASMX based webservice you can follow fletchers answer.

Comment: Ok, I looked into doing that too because I had found that WCF is the "new" flavor, but I don't see that as one of my project options when I create a new C# project.

Comment: @Leslie, what V Studio do you use? If it's the express versions you need WebDeveloper (Not C#/VB Dev).

Comment: we're using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Microsoft have removed the ability to create Web Services with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1.

It does not matter what framework you are using (2, 3, 3.5, 4) the option is not available. It is unknown at this time why Microsoft made such a move. They have been hush hush over it for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

THE BELOW SIMPLE STEPS WORKED THE BEST FOR ME....

1. create an empty website
2. rightclick -> add New item
3. and select Web Service .

This will create a empty webservice.